# Why am I receiving the error: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

When trying to cut the data in an area where the points are most concentrated I used the following code:

`filtered_data = data[(data['Word count'] <= 3500) & (data['# Shares;'] <= 8000)]`

But received the error:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*

Do you know what might be causing that error?

I have already tried including `int()` at the beginning of the line, but it didn't work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/379906/11402024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned values of `data` are strings. You're therefore trying to compare a string with an int. You need to wrap the `data`'s in an `int()` each rather than trying to wrap the whole thing. I.e.

```
filtered_data = data[(int(data['Word count']) <= 3500) & (int(data['# Shares;']) <= 8000)]
```